# Best way to define global variables from database in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to define some variables from database to take them in any place of the app (controllers and views at least).

I found a way to do this in Http/Controllers/Controller.php:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Session;
use Request;
use View;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Log;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function __construct() 
    {

        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $t = array();
            $translations = \App\Translation::all();
            foreach ($translations as $translation) {
                    $t[$translation->code] = $translation->text;
            }
            View::share('t', $t);
        });
    }
}
```

It works fine - I can access {{$t['something'}} in my app, but there is a problem with Auth route `/register` or `/login`, in these pages `$t` variable is not defined.

I think because Auth performs some actions before this my __construct, how to fix it?

Or maybe there is a better way to set dynamic variables from database reachable in all app views and controllers?

(laravel 5.3) I'm new to laravel, so can't feel the architecture yet.

Comment: Why just don't create a file `cfg` ?

Comment: sorry, new to laravel, don't know how to do this. Can I make db calls there?

Comment: How about shifting your middleware to a file and referencing it from the Auth controllers (which call the Auth views that are missing your variables)? You can first try adding your middleware logic directly in the close, and then move to a file after you see it working. See my answer below.

Comment: Does my answer make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with setting a custom Config like this:

```
 Config::set('translations', your_array_from_database);
```

You can even define your own helper function for fast retrieving, ie.

```
function t($name)
{
     return Config::get('translations.'.$name);
```

You can set your own translations Config in a middleware, so you can decide the exact order in the request-response cycle you want to load it from database.

Comment: hmm can't reach Config::get('translations') in the views - it is empty after using this code :(

Comment: but I can receive variables in any other actions not from the Auth. So it means Auth somehow renders his actions before I set Config::...?

Comment: Set your config in a middleware, as I wrote in the answer you can decide when the middleware is called in the request cycle

Comment: how can I change the order of what is called in request cycle?

Comment: you can find in the docs how to write a custom middleware and call it in the request cycle: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware

Answer (score 0):

Try using `compact` function in Laravel. Something like this:

```
//function to fetch data
//$t = \App\Translation::all();
return View::make('gameworlds.mygame', compact(['t']));
```

Then on the view you can access it like:

```
{{$t}}
```

Comment: Using View::make instead of View::share still doesn't define variables

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Laravel for some time but my guess is, based on the 5.3 docs, is you can just [call your middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#controller-middleware) from those Auth controllers that are missing it. In the [Auth Register controller](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.3/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php) you can add middleware, for example:

**app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');

    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        // Add your middleware logic here 
        // or put it in it's own file and reference like 'guest' above.

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Try your logic directly in the closure above first. Then shift to its own class file and [add it to the routeMiddleware array in the kernel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes).

Alternatively, you could include the middleware in your base controller you extend from: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.3/app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php

Comment: If I will put my code here it means that it works only with actions in this controller? And need these variables globally...

Comment: I thought you were able to add them globally to all views except the Auth ones? This is how you would cover for the Auth ones. You could include the middleware in the base controller as well. All your controllers can extend the base controller. I'll update my answer to mention that.

Comment: Updated answer.